# Nullable Guid via web service

Tags: .net, web-services

I am trying to pass a nullable Guid view the .net web service, and it always fails. But there is no problem with passing nullable DateTime object. How can i solve it?
Thanks

jAX: I pass (Guid?)null

Daniel Hilgarth: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

Comment: what u passed as nullable Guid.. ??

Comment: What means "it fails"? What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be better to pass `Guid.Empty` to the service?